# Meaning of initializing the Big Decimal to -99 in the below code

Tags: java, hashtable

I know hashtable doesnt allow null keys ...but how is the below code working.

And what does initializing the Big Decimal to -99 in the below code do.

```
private static final BigDecimal NO_REGION = new BigDecimal (-99);

public List getAllParameters (BigDecimal region, String key) {
    List values = null;
    if (region==null) {
        region = NO_REGION;
    }
    Hashtable paramCache = (Hashtable)CacheManager.getInstance().get(ParameterCodeConstants.PARAMETER_CACHE);
    if (paramCache.containsKey(region)) {
        values = (List) ((Hashtable)paramCache.get(region)).get(key); 
    }

    return values;
}
```

Am struggling for a long time and dont understand it.

Comment: `static final` of an immutable object is the Java approximation to constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an implementation of the [*null object pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern): a special object, `BigDecimal(-99)`, is designated to play the role of `null` in a situation where "real" `null`s are not allowed.

The only requirement is that the null object must be different from all "regular" objects. This way, the next time the program needs to find entries with no region, all it needs to do is a lookup by the `NO_REGION` key.

Answer (score 1):

Regions are identified by a BigDecimal in the hashtable (key) - when no region is provided (null) a default value of -99 is used.

Answer (score 1):

It just looks like poor code to me - if something that short makes you "struggle for a long time", that is usually the best indicator.

Just cleaning it up a little and it probably will make a lot more sense:

```
private static Hashtable paramCache = (Hashtable)CacheManager.getInstance().get(ParameterCodeConstants.PARAMETER_CACHE);

public List getAllParameters (BigDecimal region, String key) {
    List values = null;
    if (region != null && paramCache.containsKey(region)) {
        Hashtable regionMap = (Hashtable) paramCache.get(region); 
        values = (List) regionMap.get(key); 
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the writer into hashtable used NO_REGION as key for values without a region. So, the reader is doing the same thing.